# Get number of days between two dates datepicker and manual select too

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am looking to try and calculate the number of days between 2 datepicker fields and display that value in an input field.

How get number of days between two dates datepicker and manual select too?

This work manual select only:

```
$(function() {
$("#arrdatepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "calendar-ico.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        //dateText comes in as MM/DD/YY
        var datePieces = dateText.split('/');
        var month = datePieces[0];
        var day = datePieces[1];
        var year = datePieces[2];
        //define select option values for
        //corresponding element
        $('select#arrmonth').val(month);
        $('select#arrday').val(day);
        $('select#arryear').val(year);

    }
});
$("#depdatepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "calendar-ico.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        //dateText comes in as MM/DD/YY
        var datePieces = dateText.split('/');
        var month = datePieces[0];
        var day = datePieces[1];
        var year = datePieces[2];
        //define select option values for
        //corresponding element
        $('select#depmonth').val(month);
        $('select#depday').val(day);
        $('select#depyear').val(year);

    }
});
});

function dateDifference() {
    var ev,honap,nap;
    var datDate1 = new Date();
    var datDate2 = new Date();
    var napok;
    ev = document.booking.arrivalyear.value;
    honap = document.booking.arrivalmonth.value-1;
    nap = document.booking.arrivalday.value;
    datDate1.setFullYear(ev,honap,nap);
    ev = document.booking.departureyear.value;
    honap = document.booking.departuremonth.value-1;
    nap = document.booking.departureday.value;
    datDate2.setFullYear(ev,honap,nap);
    napok = Math.floor((datDate2-datDate1)/(24*60*60*1000));
    document.getElementById('label').innerHTML=napok+" nights";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function dateDifference() {
    // check if both is not empty
    if($("#depdatepicker").val()=='' || $("#depdatepicker").val()=='') return;

    var diff = ($("#depdatepicker").datepicker("getDate") - 
                $("#arrdatepicker").datepicker("getDate")) /
               1000 / 60 / 60 / 24; // days
    $('#label').html(diff+" nights");
}
```

Get both dates, subtract dep from arrival, you get number of milliseconds difference.

Divide by 1000ms, 60secs, 60mins, 24hours - you get number of days.

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/5SCM5/9/